# build is missing for compiling kernel module

Tags: linux, compiling, kernel-modules

this is my first time trying to create a kernel module, apparently after creating a module I need to follow these steps to compile it:

```
echo "obj-m := Hello.c" > Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=$PWD modules
```

here's my problem, there is no "build" in "/lib/modules/`uname -r`/" directory!

what am I missing here?

Comment: What flavor / distribution of Linux are you using?

Comment: @steeldriver Debian Jessie, sorry forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 1):

just found it, the following package is missing and needs to be installed before compiling any Linux kernel module:

```
sudo apt-get install -y linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

then we're ready to compile the module

```
echo "obj-m := Hello.c" > Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=$PWD modules
sudo insmod Hello.ko
```

Comment: I'm more familiar with Ubuntu, but I believe it's recommended to install the appropriate architecture-specific metapackage instead - that way, the headers should be updated automatically when the kernel is updated e.g. [linux-headers-amd64](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/linux-headers-amd64)

Comment: @steeldriver I believe this is right and more appropriate, you should add this as an answer, I'll set it as main solution, and tnx